# .Net8 Azure Functions not detected

Tags: azure-functions, .net-8.0

I am migrating our current **Azure Functions** from **.net6** to **.net8**. In order to do that, I use the **Upgrade Assistant**. In a first stage, everything seems to be working fine, as after the upgrade finish, the functions still running locally on my machine, however when I deploy it to the **Azure**, I got the following error when he function attempts to execute

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

After reaching Microsoft for Support, they recommend me to follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8#upgrade-your-local-project. The only this that differs from my Project where the packages references in point 4

```
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Once I make these changes, everything stops working. Now when I try to execute the code on my machine, I got the following

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)

It seems that now the Functions are not even recognized. Afterthat I perform the following modification based on **GitHub Copilot** suggestions:

1. Change my Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
namespace maintenance
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Add Startup.cs to project

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(maintenance.Startup))]
namespace maintenance
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Configure services or add other registrations if needed
            var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(x => new BlobServiceClient(connectionString));
            builder.Services.AddFunctionsWorkerDefaults();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Modify my function app code

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
namespace myworkspace.functions.myfunction
{
    public class MyFunction
    {
        [Function("MyFunction")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 */8 * * 5")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# MyFunction Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Even with all of this changes seems that the functions are not recognized as I get the same **No jobs functions found** message.

Do you know what should be do to fix this? I tried creating a new function in the project from scratch by it was loaded either.

Comment: What is your requirement? Are you trying to create a timer trigger isolated function in .Net 8?

Comment: mostly I have time triggers, just a few http triggers one, but none of them are found when I run the project. I need to find a way for them to be detected and can use them

Comment: what was the error you got, when you tried to create a new function?

Answer (score 1):

A .Net 8 Isolated Function with Http Trigger and Timer Trigger should have the below packages in its `.csproj` file.

**.csproj**-

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_77832689</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` which you are referring in your .csproj file is been deprecated. But without using this package also your function should work alike me.

[image]

I also having a Timer Trigger and Http Trigger function. Here I am not using Startup class, as to execute the mentioned functions, `Program.cs` file is sufficient.

**TimerTriggerFunction.cs**-

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class TimerTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public TimerTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TimerTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("TimerTriggeredFunction")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpTriggerFunction.cs**-

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _77832689
{
    public class HttpTriggeredFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public HttpTriggeredFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HttpTriggeredFunction>();
        }

        [Function("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**-

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**local.settings.json**-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

Having all these configurations in place, I am able to get the expected response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Azure Functions Core Tools. That did the trick for me. I am guessing the older version that ran functions from .Net runtime 6 doesn't know what to do with functions from .Net runtime 8.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools?tab=readme-ov-file#installing